# Filtros de busqueda usando Mysql con el framework de laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ajax, datatable

Hola buenas tardes estoy ocupando laravel y mysql para un projecto pero me he topado con una duda al realiar busquedas especificas dentro de la db, los datos los voy mostrando en un DataTable, bueno para ello les quiero mostrar la forma en como lo estoy haciendo mi pregunta seria hay una forma de optimizar este tipo de busquedas? ya que se me hace muy tedioso y eso es que solo son 3 campos y se tiene que buscar todas las combinaciones posibles de los campos que el usuario llene, y si fueran mas de 3 campos ejemplo 10 seria un caos total

```
public function viewBusinessInformation(Request $request )
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            if(!empty($request->nombre_empresa) && !empty($request->giro_empresa) && $request->nombre_estado!="selected")
            {
                $data2=DB::table('empresa')
                ->join('direccion','direccion.Id_Direccion','=','empresa.Id_Direccion')
                ->join('estado','estado.Id_Estado','=','direccion.Id_Estado')
                ->join('municipio','municipio.Id_Municipio','=','direccion.Id_Municipio')
                ->join('asentamiento','asentamiento.Id_Asentamiento','=','direccion.Id_Asentamiento')
                ->join('cp','cp.Id_Cp','=','direccion.Id_Cp')
                ->select('empresa.Id_Empresa','empresa.Nombre','empresa.Telefono','empresa.Extension','empresa.Email','empresa.Giro','empresa.Giro_Especifico','empresa.Razon_Social','estado.Nombre_Estado','municipio.Nombre_Municipio','asentamiento.Nombre_Colonia','cp.Cp','direccion.Id_Direccion','direccion.Calle1','direccion.Calle2','direccion.Interior','direccion.Exterior')
                ->where('empresa.Nombre','LIKE',"%{$request->nombre_empresa}%")
                ->where('empresa.Giro','LIKE',"%{$request->giro_empresa}%")
                ->where('estado.Id_Estado','=',$request->nombre_estado)
                ->get();
            }
            else if(!empty($request->nombre_empresa) && !empty($request->giro_empresa) && $request->nombre_estado=="selected")
            {
                $data2=DB::table('empresa')
                ->join('direccion','direccion.Id_Direccion','=','empresa.Id_Direccion')
                ->join('estado','estado.Id_Estado','=','direccion.Id_Estado')
                ->join('municipio','municipio.Id_Municipio','=','direccion.Id_Municipio')
                ->join('asentamiento','asentamiento.Id_Asentamiento','=','direccion.Id_Asentamiento')
                ->join('cp','cp.Id_Cp','=','direccion.Id_Cp')
                ->select('empresa.Id_Empresa','empresa.Nombre','empresa.Telefono','empresa.Extension','empresa.Email','empresa.Giro','empresa.Giro_Especifico','empresa.Razon_Social','estado.Nombre_Estado','municipio.Nombre_Municipio','asentamiento.Nombre_Colonia','cp.Cp','direccion.Id_Direccion','direccion.Calle1','direccion.Calle2','direccion.Interior','direccion.Exterior')
                ->where('empresa.Nombre','LIKE',"%{$request->nombre_empresa}%")
                ->where('empresa.Giro','LIKE',"%{$request->giro_empresa}%")
                ->get();
            }
            else if(!empty($request->nombre_empresa) && empty($request->giro_empresa) && $request->nombre_estado=="selected")
            {
                $data2=DB::table('empresa')
                ->join('direccion','direccion.Id_Direccion','=','empresa.Id_Direccion')
                ->join('estado','estado.Id_Estado','=','direccion.Id_Estado')
                ->join('municipio','municipio.Id_Municipio','=','direccion.Id_Municipio')
                ->join('asentamiento','asentamiento.Id_Asentamiento','=','direccion.Id_Asentamiento')
                ->join('cp','cp.Id_Cp','=','direccion.Id_Cp')
                ->select('empresa.Id_Empresa','empresa.Nombre','empresa.Telefono','empresa.Extension','empresa.Email','empresa.Giro','empresa.Giro_Especifico','empresa.Razon_Social','estado.Nombre_Estado','municipio.Nombre_Municipio','asentamiento.Nombre_Colonia','cp.Cp','direccion.Id_Direccion','direccion.Calle1','direccion.Calle2','direccion.Interior','direccion.Exterior')
                ->where('empresa.Nombre','LIKE',"%{$request->nombre_empresa}%")
                ->get();
            }
            

            else
            {
                $data2=DB::table('empresa')
                ->join('direccion','direccion.Id_Direccion','=','empresa.Id_Direccion')
                ->join('estado','estado.Id_Estado','=','direccion.Id_Estado')
                ->join('municipio','municipio.Id_Municipio','=','direccion.Id_Municipio')
                ->join('asentamiento','asentamiento.Id_Asentamiento','=','direccion.Id_Asentamiento')
                ->join('cp','cp.Id_Cp','=','direccion.Id_Cp')
                ->select('empresa.Id_Empresa','empresa.Nombre','empresa.Telefono','empresa.Extension','empresa.Email','empresa.Giro','empresa.Giro_Especifico','empresa.Razon_Social','estado.Nombre_Estado','municipio.Nombre_Municipio','asentamiento.Nombre_Colonia','cp.Cp','direccion.Id_Direccion','direccion.Calle1','direccion.Calle2','direccion.Interior','direccion.Exterior')
                ->get();
            }
            
            return datatables()->of($data2)->make(true);
        }
```

aqui estoy evaluando dependiendo si los campos estan vacios o contienen algun valor por defecto y en ba se a eso se retorna el valor al DataTable, aun me faltan terminar las demas combinaciones posibles con los 3 campos que estoy trabajando, alquien sabe como optimizar este tipo de busquedas para evitar tanta redundancia de codigo?
gracias de antemano un saludo

Comment: Revisate el uso del método `when` para cláusulas condicionales. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses te va a facilitar mucho la vida y evitar diñuplicidad de código

Comment: Perfecto ya la estoy mirando y se ve prometedor para evitar la duplicidad, muchas gracias la voy a implementar y comento que tal me fue